# viewWiillappear not call when pop view in ios 4.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

ViewWillappear is called when push one contrller but when you pop this controller, in this case viewwillappear not call in ios 4.3.5 . But it works fin in ios 5.0.It little bit urgent.please tell me.
Thank in advance.

Comment: writ this code when you back to previous screen
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

Just send a viewWillAppear message to your view controller before you add it as a subview/PopView. (There is one BOOL parameter which tells the view controller if it's being animated to appear or not.)

`[myViewController viewWillAppear:NO];`

Look at RootViewController.m in the Metronome example.

(I actually found Apple's example projects great. There's a LOT more than HelloWorld ;)